# Android SQLite causing crash

Tags: android, sqlite, crash

My app crashes pretty much straight away whenever this method is called, and I have been messing with it for hours now. I'm pretty new to SQL and even newer to Android programming so does anything jump out straight away as being wrong with me code here? I think I may be missing something else that you have to do with the cursor but I don't have anyone to ask. Thanks in advance:

```
public String fillTimetable(String day, String week, String lesson){
    String[] column = new String[]{KEY_SUBJECT};
    String selection = "WHERE "+KEY_DAY+" = '"+day+"' AND "+KEY_WEEK+" = '"+week+"' AND "+KEY_LESSON+" = '"+lesson+"';";
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, column, selection, null, null,
            null, null);

    int iSubject = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SUBJECT);
    return c.getString(iSubject);

}//end fillTimetable
```

Log Cat report:

```
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.shearer.schooltimetable/com.shearer.schooltimetable.Tabs}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062):     at com.shearer.schooltimetable.Tabs.<init>(Tabs.java:19)
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
02-27 22:17:52.180: E/AndroidRuntime(8062):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You are missing something...the logcat from the crash. Please edit your post and add it so we can help you easier.

Comment: Since the cursor is positioned BEFORE the first row, you should always move it to the first record: `c.moveToFirst();` before consuming it. From the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29): `Returns: A Cursor object, which is positioned before the first entry.`

Answer (score 1):

From the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
at com.shearer.schooltimetable.Tabs.<init>(Tabs.java:19)
```

you're calling `findViewById()` before `setContentView()`. Move the call from member variable initialization to activity `onCreate()` after `setContentView()`.

From the code you posted, the `selection` should omit the `WHERE`:

```
String selection = KEY_DAY+" = '"+day+"' AND "+KEY_WEEK+" = '"+week+"' AND "+KEY_LESSON+" = '"+lesson+"';";
```

It would also be wise to use `?` placeholders for literals with `selectionArgs` to e.g. avoid SQL injection, for example:

```
String selection = KEY_DAY+" = ? AND "+KEY_WEEK+" = ? AND "+KEY_LESSON+" = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { day, week, lesson };
Cursor c = ...query(..., selection, selectionArgs, ...);
```

After `query()` the `Cursor` doesn't yet point to a valid result row. Use one of the `moveTo...` methods to move it before trying to access row data with `getString()`:

```
Cursor c = ....;
String result = null;
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    int iSubject = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SUBJECT);
    result = c.getString(iSubject);
}
c.close();
return result;
```

It's also a good idea to explicitly close your cursors as shown above.

Comment: I changed my code as you explained to try and fix it, but my app is still crashing. I was getting this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activityComponentInfo{com.shearer.schooltimetable/com.shearer.schooltimetable.Tabs}: java.lang.NullPointerException
, which I thought may be because I hadn't factored in what to do if the database returned "null", but that still didnt fix it. Any ideas? Sorry

Comment: Look at the line number of the NPE exception and see where in your code it points to.

Comment: It points to where I try and draw data from the db, is this not an okay way to avoid the NPE? - if (temp != null) {
    tvs[i].setText(temp);
   }

Comment: Either `tvs` or `tvs[i]` is null. You can use a debugger to find out. However, it seems it's no longer related to this question, so if you have trouble with it, consider posting a new question.